# How can I submit my proxy and name on localhost

Tags: php, forms, curl

If I submit the form I want `register.php` to fetch the proxy and name which I'm submitting from `client.php`

if I don't use `action='register.php'` then it's printing the proxy I have submitted but not printing the name.

But if I use `action='register.php'` to post my form to `register.php` then it's printing my localhost `IP: 127.0.0.1` instead of the proxy I have submitted.

I don't know why curl request isn't submitting my proxy when I use `register.php` in `action=''` tag.

```
if(!isset($_GET['name'])){

echo "<form class='' method='get' action='register.php'>
    
    <input id='cat' type='text' name='name' maximum='10' placeholder='Enter Name' autocomplete='off' required></input>
   <input id='cat' type='text' name='proxy' placeholder='Enter Your Proxy ' autocomplete='off'></input>
    <input class='button' type='submit' value='Submit'></input>
    </form>";
    
    }

if(isset($_GET['name'])){

        $number = $_GET['name'];
        $proxy = $_GET['proxy'];

        
    $headers['CLIENT-IP'] = $proxy;

    $headers['X-FORWARDED-FOR'] = $proxy;
    
    $headerArr = array();
    
    Foreach( $headers as $n => $v ) {
    
    $headerArr[] = $n .':' . $v;
    
    }


Ob_start();

$ch = curl_init();

Curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/register.php");

Curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , $headerArr ); //Structure IP

Curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

#Curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

#Curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

Curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

Curl_exec($ch);

Curl_close ($ch);

$out = ob_get_contents();

Ob_clean();

Echo $out;
}
```

this is my register.php

the name and proxy I'm submitting from client.php should be print here.

```
Function GetIP(){

if(!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))

$cip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];

else if(!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))

$cip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

else if(!empty($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]))

$cip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

else

$cip = "Unable to get!";

return $cip;

}

echo"IP: ". GetIP (). "
"; 


$name = $_GET['name'];

echo $name
```

Result is

```
Ip: 127.0.0.1 \\ here I want to print the proxy I have submitted
Rohan
```

Comment: have you printed the entire `$_SERVER` array out?  Does your proxy display anywhere in the output when you  `print_r( $_SERVER );` ?  --  I have a feeling it's getting lost in the logic of all your `else-ifs`

Comment: You have a function called `ip()` that I'm not seeing used anywhere?

Comment: @Zak yes sir it's showing if I use ```print_r($_SERVER):.

Comment: This is the result I'm getting by using ```print_r($_SERVER);``` [Img](https://imgur.com/UYz6eld)

Comment: @ChrisHaas that function fetches IP sir.

Comment: @Sourav -- The function fetches the IP .. True .. But the function isn't being **used**  IE `$returned_ip = ip(); echo $returned_ip;`

Comment: @Zak sir I have updated my code a little please have a look what's Wrong here.

Comment: Now -- Since you say it's showing in `print_r` you need to adjust your `if else` to make sure it stops on the correct parameter.

Comment: You've got `client.php` and `register.php`. In `client.php` you have a form with two fields. If that forms points to `register.php`, it is your browser making that call using your browser's proxy settings, the server curl doesn't get invoked, and you cannot make any changes to the browser's proxy using the server's settings. The world would break if that could happen. If the form points to `client.php`, then it is curl making the call and you can override things.

Comment: @ChrisHaas so is there any way to make that happen sir ? Cause if I make my form points to ```client.php```  then it won't print the name. ```register.php```  won't be able to fetch the name. Is there any solution available sir ?